# automatization script for startup program

Tags: bash, automation

I want an application which controls my RGB lights, which starts up on boot to be clicked on a few buttons via a script. I want a button to be clicked so the RGB profile gets loaded and then the close button of the application.

I have looked around for bash scripts that interact with programs but it probably doesn't work that way since I have seen zero answers and the program is already compiled, so can't call functions. What is the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: If you want buttons I think bash is the wrong way to go

Comment: I agree. You can use Qt directly on the framebuffer and write a program. Otherwise maybe xdotool?

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I found what I'm looking for. I'm experimenting with AutoHotkey will update if it works.

Comment: I forgot to respond to this thread. I fixed the problem with AutoHotKey. It is perfect for interacting with an GUI on windows.